# Django default model fields in the models.Model class

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class:

```
class Something(models.Model):
     field1 = Charfield()
     field2 = Charfield()
     field3 = Integerfield()
```

And I want to give every user that signs up some default models. A.k.

```
 default_something = [
     {'field1':'char1',
      'field2':'char2',
      'field3':'int1',
      },
     {'field1':'char3',
      'field2':'char4',
      'field3':'int2',
     }]
```

Now I would like to reference the default values based on the name in my code in the save method of the class... but it should only select the default ones, and not the ones that a user might have added with the same name!

Therefore I keep an extra field, field4 which keeps an integer (default_id) and then I can select on basis of this default_id...

Is this the best way to do this? Or how should you do it?

Answer (score 0):

you dont need 4th field, you can get the default value of the field e.g. `field1` like this:

```
field1 = Something._meta.get_field_by_name('field1')
field1.default
```

Comment: But what if a user created fields with the same name? Or maybe I should make sure that users cannot create a field with the same name

Comment: what do you mean with "creating field"? I dont think your users can create a field in your database easily

Comment: I'm sorry, what if the user created an instance of the model where field1 has the same value

Comment: you will deal with one object at a time, if an object has field1 empty, then this object will have the same default value as the other objects have. with one word - you can define only **one** default value for one field.

Comment: Ah, that is not exactly what I wanted, I have different default values, which should be created when the user signs up.

Comment: you cannot give different default values for one field - thats impossible. in other words, those values are not default values anymore..

Comment: Why not? Just create multiple instances?

Comment: each instance will have the same default value which is defined in your model.